# Use of greater than or equals(>=) and lesser than or equals(<=) in SQL SELECT statements and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to make a small function to determine grades from a set of ranges stored in a MySQL database  i.e A is between 80 and 100,A- is between 74 and 79 and so on. Am using PDO and prepared statements. However PDO does not give me the result. Could someone please help me resolve this.Below is the table preview

[image: table review]

```
<?php
     include("./inc/db.php");
    //i have set PDO attribute to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in the connection file
    //this code has failed to work
    $mark = 85;

    try{
        $pk = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grading WHERE ? BETWEEN min AND max");
        $pk->bindParam(1,$mark);
        $pk->execute();
        $ind=$pk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $ind['grade'];
    } catch(PDOexception $f) {
        echo $f->getMessage();   
    }

//however when i try this it displays the grade. whats wrong with the previous code?

    try{
        $pk = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grading WHERE 85 BETWEEN min AND max");
        $pk->execute();
        $ind=$pk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $ind['grade'];
    } catch(PDOexception $f) {
        echo $f->getMessage();   
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: `WHERE BETWEEN :max AND :min` that should work.

Comment: You use 85 for both, min and max

Comment: What about a mark of 80? Will the grade be A or will the grade be B? You shouldn't have overlapping limits. Please post your grading table, it can't be very heavy work.

Comment: `$min = 85;
 $max = 100;

        $pk = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grading WHERE max >=:max AND min <=:min");
        $pk->bindParam(':min',$min);
        $pk->bindParam(':max',$mark);`
 
--- OR --- 

    `$min = 85;
 $max = 100;

        $pk = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grading WHERE BETWEEN :max AND :min");
        $pk->bindParam(':min',$min);
        $pk->bindParam(':max',$mark);`

Comment: I have posted the table. I need it to display a grade whenever a mark is input. If one keys in 75 it should give A-

Comment: Use a conditional statement then along with a ternary operator, in conjunction with what I've already commented on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the logic a little. Just like Phoenix Wright, sometimes all it takes it flipping things around to solve them:

```
$pk = $db->prepare("SELECT `grade` FROM `grading` WHERE ? BETWEEN `min` and `max`");
$pk->execute(array($mark));
$ind = $pk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $ind['grade'];
```

Using a value as the first operand for `BETWEEN` and `IN` is not something many people would think of, yet it's so powerful ;)

---

More importantly (and thanks to Fred -ii- for accidentally helping me realise), `min` and `max` are function names. If you want to use them as column names, you *must* wrap them in backticks, as I have done in my code above.

As a general rule, you should *always* put backticks around your table and column names. Not doing so is akin to writing `$foo = bar;` in PHP. Sure, it'll *work*, but if `bar` happens to be a constant or function name then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: *"is not something many people would think of"* - True. However, in light of OP's [`comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220619/use-of-greater-than-or-equals-and-lesser-than-or-equals-in-sql-select-st#comment39283533_25220619) *"need it to display a grade whenever a mark is input. If one keys in 75 it should give A"* this would require some form of a conditional statement and maybe a ternary operator.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure I follow. The input mark should be passed in as `$mark`, surely?

Comment: OP is using the same variable `$mark` for both min and max. Will what you posted work and take two different inputs into consideration? I think OP may need to show us a bit more code, along with how the inputs are taken from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My understanding is that a single value is given (`$mark`) but it is bound twice (as `:min` and `:max`) because you can't use the same parameter more than once in a prepared query (unless PDO emulates support for you). The query I've given uses a single parameter for the single value given, simplifying things and reducing the potential for errors.

Comment: OP originally posted `$mark = 85;` but didn't put it back in doing the edit. That translates to `WHERE max 85 AND 85` by OP's method. Hard for "me" to give a definite answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see it as `WHERE max >= 85 AND min <= 85`, which is an awkward way of saying `min <= 85 <= max`, which itself can be translated to `85 BETWEEN min AND max`... aaaaand I've just realised why the query wasn't working.

Comment: +1 I guess when we "think outloud", we realize where we may have gone wrong ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hehe... it was actually the moment of hesitation when I was going to put backticks around the column names, and then realised that because Markdown I needed to double up the surrounding ones, and then waitaminute there weren't any in the original question and ooooohhhh XD

Comment: Now, to await the OP's response. Ok, I gotta run. *Cheers*

Comment: Apologies something happened during the editing.Let me try to put it clear again.As you can see ,there are different ranges for the grades as i had initially posted. the $mark=85 was supposed to act as a data input variable whose expected result should have been A.
the following query has worked.$pk=$db->prepare("SELECT grade FROM grading WHERE 85 BETWEEN min AND max");.i wonder why the query with the placeholder "?" isnt working even after binding parameters

Comment: @AstroguyPasa Have you set PDO into Exception Mode? Otherwise your `try..catch` is useless as errors are silently ignored. It's a stupid default mode, but... -shrugs- Anyway, I need to ask you that now XD

Comment: What about `WHERE $max BETWEEN ...`? Seems like you want to bind a column, which can't be done.

Comment: @AstroguyPasa Try putting the backticks around your column names. Also, try `bindValue` rather than `bindParam`... in fact, why don't you go ahead and just copy-paste my code? :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol.Thanks alot.bindValue works well..phewcs..after so long..:)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please check out this link and help me know why the function does not return (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222921/function-fails-to-return-value/25227615#25227615)

Answer (score 0):

You can write 2 different queries:

```
 $pk = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grading WHERE max >=:max AND min <=:min");
```

OR

```
$pk = $db->prepare("SELECT SOMETHING FROM grading WHERE SOMETHING BETWEEN max AND min");
```

But in your case the first one works. the problem is that you are using the same variable `$mark` for both min and max

Comment: I needed to use the same thing in order for it to make a decision of range.

Comment: @AstroguyPasa you are saying that for example you select A where min and max are the same ? but in your table as shown in your post they don't match each other. if there is another thing which hasn't been mentioned explain about that

Comment: take a look at my update question. Maybe that might give a bit of clear quest

Comment: In your first code replace `?` with `:mark` and change `$pk->bindParam(1,$mark);` with `$pk->bindParam(':mark',$mark);` This must work. use bindValue as well to see if it works