# Function fails to return value

Tags: php, pdo

i have tried a code both in and out of the function and it has showed some very quire characteristics.It works perfectly well when out of the function but when included in the function, nothing is returned. Help me reconstruct the function well.

```
   <?php

    function detgrade($con,$mrk){

     $pk=$con->prepare("SELECT grade FROM grading WHERE ? BETWEEN min_mark AND max_mark");
     $pk->bindValue(1,$mrk);
     $pk->execute();
     $ind=$pk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $gr = $ind['grade'];

    return $gr;
    }
   //calling the function
     echo detgrade($db,87);

   ?>
```

Comment: instead of echoing you should try with var_dump for inspecting variables

Comment: the problem is you cannot use placeholders on a `WHERE ?` clause because it is a column you cannot bindvalue

Comment: @NaingLinAung `var_dump` returns `null`

Comment: @meda the code works well when not put in a function even with `bindValue`. why would it fail to work in a function?

Comment: From the database in your previous [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220619/use-of-greater-than-or-equals-and-lesser-than-or-equals-in-sql-select-st) you name the columns min & max. In your query you use min_mark & max_mark. The query works with the correct names

Comment: i actually changed the column names in the database to min_mark and max_mark

Comment: the query does work but only when it is not enclosed in the function. why would it fail when in a function?

Comment: As I said earlier the function works. I changed test database to new names and it still works.You must be leaving something out. What error message are you getting?

Comment: No message at all. It gives a null result

Answer (score 1):

The fetch result returns an array of objects, so grabbing the 'grade' key on an array of objects won't return anything. Try

```
$gr = $ind[0]['grade'];
```

Comment: no, the array is one object not 2-dimensional. The only time you do this is when you use `fetchAll()` and want to access the first object